# Image required or doable with CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to create at the aside `a` navigation bar. Now I want to know if I need a picture or if I can solve it with CSS. I want a transition effect if I hover over the link. Here is the picture of the problem:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an image (preferably SVG, so it’s vector-based) is probably the easier option here. However, it is possible using CSS by exploiting the way borders are drawn.

Details here: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/

I’ve used that technique and applied it to your example: http://jsfiddle.net/s9tn5yqe/

[image: Nav Bar]

**CSS:**

```
.nav {
    width: 160px;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin: 32px;
    border: 2px solid #000;
}
.nav li {
    width: 96px;
    display: block;
    height: 32px;
    margin: 32px 0;
    background-color: #000;
    border-left-width: 0;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}
.nav li:hover {
    width: 128px;
}
.nav li:after {
    content: '';
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border: 16px solid transparent;
    border-left-color: #000;
    position: absolute;
    right: -32px;
    top: 0;
}
.nav li a {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    position: absolute;
    line-height: 32px;
    top: 2px;
    left: 0;
    right: 1px;
    bottom: 2px;
    display: block;
    padding: 0 8px;
    background-color: #fff;
}
.nav li a:after {
    content: '';
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border: 14px solid transparent;
    border-left-color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    right: -28px;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

**Explanation:**

There are two layers. The first layer is the `li` element that has a black background. Additionally, a pseudo-element is added using the `:after` selector. That element has a zero width and height but a black border on the left which creates the triangle. The same technique is used for the `a` element but with white color and a bit smaller, so the black `li` element is visible and creates the desired border.

The animation is straight-forward and was already part of @Preben’s answer.

Answer (score 0):

See here:

```
<div class="side">
    <a href="#link">My link</a>
    <a href="#link">My link</a>
    <a href="#link">My link</a>
    <a href="#link">My link</a>
    <a href="#link">My link</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.side a {
       background-color:black;
       color:#fff;
       display:block;
       width:200px;
       padding:10px;
       text-decoration:none;
       clear:both;
             }
.side a:hover {
       background-color:rgb(0, 0, 0);
       background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

The ´background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);´ is black background with opacity = 0.3  The reason why I have added background-color without opacity too, is that not all browsers support opacity. It's a fallback.

**Version with *animation*:**

[image]

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Preben/09g8dtnh/1/

CSS:

```
.side a {background-color:black;color:#fff;display:block;width:200px;padding:10px;text-decoration:none;clear:both;-webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;}
.side a:hover {width:300px;background-color:rgb(0, 0, 0);background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);-webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;}
```

Comment: I don’t see how this would solve the problem. @Skeptar is asking for animating the element’s width when hovering.

Comment: Misunderstood then. Let me think a bit

Comment: My problem is the form of each link. And with the form the transition effect

Comment: Thanks for the answer its really nice! But i want the special form.

Comment: Transition is solved above. You can set the time in CSS. The form can be an image, or border. Let me look into that.

Comment: Yes could you help me with the special form? Because i dont know how to do it with css. If it works